# How to setup Smtp and webfaction email host in a single settings.py file in django1.5.1?

Tags: django, smtp, webfaction

This the one host that i created I want to add another one host also.

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True`
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' 
EMAIL_PORT = 587 `
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'developer@sangeeth' 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'developer.sangeeeth@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than one `EMAIL_HOST` cannot be defined in django `settings.py`. Read more about [email settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#email-host) and [sending emails](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/email/) in django. If you want to use different email hosts for sending emails, you can try [python smtplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html) for sending emails instead of django's email feature.